# Group Times Into Time Intervals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with contains different times. I need to classify those times into different time intervals into a new column in new dataframe.

```
df7['Time_B'] = df6.groupby([df6['Arr_Time'],pd.TimeGrouper(freq='6H')])
```

A new column with Time_B is expected. The Arrival times in HH:MM is to be classified to different time buckets i.e. 12-6, 6-12, 12-18, 18-24. How can I do this?

Comment: It is better to give a glimpse of input data and the expected output. Makes answering easier.

Comment: Origin, Destination, Dept_Date, Dept_Time, Total_Fare;;;
BLR, MAA, 2018-10-27, 00:45, 2635.0 ;;;
BLR, MAA, 2018-10-27, 10:45, 2635.0;;;
BLR, MAA, 2018-10-27, 11:45, 2635.0 ;;;
BLR, MAA, 2018-10-27, 18:45, 2635.0;;;
The input data looks like this. For the Dept_Time., to classify them to different time buckets.

I want output like this
Origin, Destination, Dept_Date, Dept_Time, Total_Fare, Time_B;;;
BLR, MAA, 2018-10-27, 00:45, 2635.0, 00-06;;; 
BLR, MAA, 2018-10-27, 10:45, 2635.0, 06-12;;;
BLR, MAA, 2018-10-27, 11:45, 2635.0, 06-12;;;
BLR, MAA, 2018-10-27, 18:45, 2635.0, 18-24;;;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I will go about it:

```
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df7 = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''
Origin, Destination, Dept_Date, Dept_Time, Total_Fare
BLR, MAA, 2018-10-27, 00:45, 2635.0
BLR, MAA, 2018-10-27, 10:45, 2635.0
BLR, MAA, 2018-10-27, 11:45, 2635.0
BLR, MAA, 2018-10-27, 18:45, 2635.0
'''))

df7
```

Input dataframe: 
[image]

To add the time slots:

```
df7["Departure"] = df7.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x[2] +' '+ x[3]), axis=1)

time_diff = df7.Departure - pd.to_datetime(df7.Departure.dt.date)

df7['Time_Slot'] = np.floor((time_diff / np.timedelta64(6, 'h')) )

interval_dict = {0.0:'00-06',
                1.0:'06-12',
                2.0:'12-18',
                3.0:'18-24'}

df7['Time_B'] = df7.Time_Slot.map(interval_dict)

del df7["Departure"]
del df7["Time_Slot"]
```

The desired output:
[image]

Hope this helps. The code can be compressed.